# Commit to SVN without changing the revision

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am commiting files to SVN via jenkins.
This file have no effect on the revision and should not update it and increase revision number. How can I commit it without updating revision number?

```
svn commit -m "Jeninkins build number update" AndroidStable/BuildNumber.txt --non-interactive --username jenkins --password jenkins
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  You want to commit a change without recording that you've committed a change?

Comment: My team checking revision number to see if something changed in the code. The file BuildNumber.txt have non effect on the code, just for releasing version. But I need them to be with the same revision if the CODE HAS NOT CHANGED. This file is irrelevant to SVN revision number

Comment: Then use a _tag_ for marking this thing as a release.

Comment: @Dim - But the code (i.e. the content of the repo) **has** changed.  You can avoid this problem entirely by auto-generating the build-number as part of compiling/publishing the build artifacts.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - I have other files to commit after build... I need this specific solution

Comment: What you are asking for isn't possible - if you want to change the content of the repo, then that's a commit, which is (by definition) a change in the SVN revision number.  As I said above, if you are auto-generating stuff, there is no need to commit it back to SVN.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ... or to any other version-control system. I'd suggest Dim to do some homework.

Comment: From your comment "My team checking revision number to see if something changed in the code" I take it your team are really looking to see if something changed in the source code (as opposed to the 'boilerplate' stuff like build number file, build.xml, etc?). So I would suggest that your team could refine how they are identifying a change to the items they are interested in (the code) rather than the whole checked-out project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are asking for isn't possible.  SVN<sup>*</sup> doesn't distinguish between "code" and "not code"; any change to the content of the repo is a commit, which is (by definition) a bump in the revision number.

If your aim is to just incorporate the revision number into the final build artifact, there's no need to commit it back to SVN.  You can just pull it in at build-time.

More simply: **Don't put auto-generated stuff in version-control.**

---

<sup>* Or indeed any version-control system that I'm familiar with.</sup>